# the getFiles() isn't returning all files available

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

```
 var results = DriveApp.getFiles(start,max);

 while(results.hasNext()) {
  var result = results.next();
 }
 Logger.log("test");
```

This piece of code should find me all my files from my-drive but I only receive 5 files out of 7 - can anyone help ?

Comment: I am not familiar with a version of `DriveApp.getFiles` that takes two parameters - are they input parameters? What values do they have when this code executes?

Comment: i am trying to take all files from drive so i can search for a containing text

Comment: [`getFiles()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles) takes no parameters. What can you tell us about the files that are supposedly not shown or accessed by this loop?

Comment: The code isn't complete by the other hand the getFiles method apparently is wrong so the Google Apps Script editor should return an error. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: yes the code isn't complete found out the error am taking the values and sending them as attached emails , the code is freezing when sending them as emails problem fixed for me i changed the way

Comment: the API froze while attaching files from drive to email and problem fixed thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to return all files as instructed by the [Apps Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/):

```
// Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, for me at least, which is: why doesn't `DriveApp.getFiles()` return *all* files available.  In my case, when I iterate through as you have indicated, I only count about 4900 files, when there are a lot more than that.